# How do I install kbuild?

Tags: python, google-closure-compiler

How do I run/install this: https://github.com/kevmoo/kbuild?

I installed the dependencies and tried to execute the bin/kbuild Python script, but it's giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "kbuild/bin/kbuild", line 12, in <module>
   BREW_PREFIX = subprocess.check_output(['brew', '--prefix']).strip()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
   process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
   errread, errwrite)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
   raise child_exception    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

My guess is that this tool was intended for OSX and Homebrew and that's why it's choking.  I just wasn't sure based on the minimalist installation instructions.

Comment: @MattDMo: that error wasn't Python code; it was an error message in my terminal, so is syntax highlighting appropriate in this case?

Comment: This is a Python traceback, so technically a code block is appropriate. On a greater level, though, many error messages have space formatting in them that is best captured (and most easily read in) a code block. It doesn't necessarily **have** to be code, you could just as easily call it a `<pre>` block (preformatted) after the HTML tags being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 12:
`BREW_PREFIX = subprocess.check_output(['brew', '--prefix']).strip()`
is explicitly trying to run 'brew' in the shell, so yes I'd say it is written only for OSX.

I'd suggest you wait for your Issue to be answered on GitHub, or try modifying it yourself. It seems brew is only being used to check for available compilers.